# Delphi study analysis, how to calculate outcome specific stakeholder score frequency

Tags: r

I am analysing data from a Delphi study and I need to create a vector of the frequency of each score (1:10) for each stakeholder group (6 groups, total of 73 participants) for each outcome (48). The data is in the form:

[image]

I would like to create a vector similar to:

score     1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

trialists<-c(0,0,0,0,28.6,71.4,0,0,0)

Where it is expressed as a percentage of a stakeholder group (e.g. trialists) that have scored each score for each outcome . I need to excluded a score of 10 as it represents "unable to answer".

This will result in 48 vectors for each of the 6 stakeholder groups.

Is there a elegant way to do this on R rather than just plodding through the data on excel and inputting it manually?